# WSO2 - Identity server - SMS OTP on MFA customization

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I enabled an identity provider called SMSOTP and add it as federated authenticator under my service provider. I am receiving the following SMS on login (SMS channel): Verification Code: [the code]

I want to change this message and add a local text for it (same as we do for email template via IS console). Howe can i achieve this?

I tried the following:

Adding the following under: wso2is-6.1.0\repository\conf\sms\sms-templates-admin-config.xml

```
<configuration type="SMSOTP" display="SMSOTP" locale="en_US">
    <body>Your one-time password for the {{application-name}} is {{otpToken}}. This expires in {{otp-expiry-time}} minutes.</body>
</configuration>
    <configuration type="SMSOTP" display="SMSOTP" locale="fr_fr">
    <body>Votre one-time password pour {{application-name}} est {{otpToken}}. S'expire dans {{otp-expiry-time}} minutes.</body>
</configuration>
```

But it did not work even if the local of user if fr_fr (same local works fine for french email).

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The SMS used in the SMS authenticator is not configurable (The value sent into $ctx.msg). It is a constant https://github.com/wso2-extensions/identity-outbound-auth-sms-otp/blob/dfa2369c8bc5455c0b11c4c771970be06b1e0a3d/component/authenticator/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/authenticator/smsotp/SMSOTPAuthenticator.java#L1797

If you want to change the SMS OTP message and change it according to the user's locale the following alternative can be tried.

1. Go to the created Identity provider configuring SMS authenticator (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/mfa/2fa-sms-otp/#configure-the-sms-otp-authenticator)
   Keep only enable check and remove all other configurations under SMS OTP configuration as bellow.

[image]

2. Go to `wso2is-6.1.0/repository/deployment/server/eventpublishers` and open `SMSPublisher.xml`
   Configure the SMS gateway's URL         `<property name="http.url">your SMS gateway URL</property>`
   and

The SMS provider's SMS publishing endpoint payload as similar to here(Given sample is for NEXMO).
Keep the {{body}} and {{mobile}} as in same template to override by sender's mobile number and message to be sent as SMS.

```
 <inline>{"api_key"="12**33",
            "api_secret"="F**a",
            "from"="NEXMO",
            "to"={{mobile}},
            "text"={{body}}
            }
</inline>
```

3. Then go to `wso2is-6.1.0/repository/conf/sms/sms-templates-admin-config.xml` and add the following section as you have already done.

```
<configuration type="SMSOTP" display="SMSOTP" locale="fr_fr">
    <body>Votre one-time password pour {{application-name}} est {{otpToken}}. S'expire dans {{otp-expiry-time}} minutes.</body>
</configuration>
```

4. Then change the local attribute of the particular user to fr_fr

[image]

5. Try out the application login flow, authenticating from the user who has fr_fr local. He will receive the SMS that you have configured in step 3.

Comment: Thank you i will try it. Question, should it be a = or : in the inline? also will this work on a tenant service provider and user? or only on main carbon super?

Comment: = or : in the inline section is based on the API payload that should be in the SMS gateway. For the latest nexmo `=` is used. 
For tenants, you have to register SMS publisher tenant wise. https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/notification-sender-rest-api/#/SMS%20Senders/createSMSSender

Comment: For the main tenant it is working perfectly. But for tenant: I applied the steps above on the tenant, if i use the sms publisher under repository\deployment\server\eventpublishers it does not send the correct french message as if its the default config. I tried to put the sms publisher under: repository\tenants\1 where i created a new eventpublishers folder but i got an error in the logs saying that the sms publisher is already configured. I tried to modify repository\components\features\org.wso2.carbon.event.handler.notification.server_1.7.7 as well but its not working.

Comment: I tried the flow in a tenant other than super tenant and the flow worked fine with the same SMS publisher. Did you change the local claim of the user in the tenant correctly? If you want to add a tenant specific sms provider, adding a file under the tenant folder will not work. You have to use the API I mentioned above to configure the SMS provider for the tenant. https://medium.com/@anuradha-15/tenant-wise-email-and-sms-notification-senders-in-wso2-identity-server-43554e1a5afe you can find more details from here